# Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick?

Tags: qt, qml, cross-compiling, toolchain

I am trying to deploy a **QT** application into a **iOS** device,

**Step1 :** I downloaded the qtbase source code from the git hub     https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase.git

**Step2** : After the qtbase was downloaded i just went inside the folder qtbase and ran a command (am using mac mini-osx 10.10.4 yosemite)

> ./configure -xplatform macx-ios-clang -release

**Step3** : then am running

> make

and

> make install

**Step4 :** The libraries are successfully built in /usr/local/QT 5.6/lib

**Step5 :** Now an creating a QT quick application and mentioning the clang-iphone kit.

**Step6 :** Now if I try to build ,it saying , **ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick**

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: So you just compiled qtbase, not qtdeclarative?

Comment: You've only compiled the modules that are in the base git module - so `core`, `sql`, `gui`, `widgets`... You need to compile the other modules that you need, too.

Comment: @peppe: am new to qt...so can u explain what is qtdeclarative??

Comment: Why don't you just use the prebuilt packages? Anyhow, it's another git repository that you need to clone and compile (using the `qmake` you have when you installed qtbase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install `qtdeclarative5-dev` package:

```
sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

This worked for me